# How do I integrate a json file generated from a gitlab job in project p1 into a python script in project p2?

Tags: python, terraform, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I have two projects in gitlab,p1, p2. In p1 '.gitlab-ci.yml' file it performs a terraform module deployment in the the apply stage it generates a json file which is located in the artifacts. In p2 we have python script that creates a pdf out of a json file, Now how to pass that json file from p1 job artifacts to p2 python project and generate a pdf. Ex: whenever the p1's'.gitlab-ci.yml' runs Its generates a json file which is stored in the artifacts and it should trigger the p2, and p2's '.gitlab-ci.yml' should integrate the json file located in p1's atifacts and create a pdf based on the python script.

How to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

Using [multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Multi-project+pipeline) you can trigger the pipeline of p2 from the pipeline of p1. In the pipeline for p2, you can [fetch artifacts from the upstream pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Multi-project+pipeline#fetch-artifacts-from-an-upstream-pipeline), in this case the json file.

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` for p1, you may have a job that looks something like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - downstream
tf_apply:
  stage: build
  script:
    - make apply > output.json  # or whatever
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - output.json

trigger_downstream:
  stage: downstream
  variables:
    UPSTREAM_REF: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  trigger:
    project: project-group/path/to/p2
```

Then in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` for p2 you might have something that looks like this:

```yaml
make_pdf:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cat output.json  # we have the artifact from the upstream p1 job
    - make pdf --input-file=output.json
  needs:
    - project: project/path/to/p1
      job: tf_apply
      ref: $UPSTREAM_REF
      artifacts: true
```